# Trying to show an OSM/Nominatim relation on an OpenLayers 3 map

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers-3, overpass-api, nominatim

I am trying to show the boundary of relation **4569(Brugge, West Flanders, Flanders, Knokke-Heist)** on an OpenLayers 3 type map, like http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org . But I don't know how to proceed.

These are the things I am doing:

1. I am querying Overpass API with the following parameters:

`data=[output:json];relation(4569); out geom; out center;`

This query gives me back the information about the relation with the id of 4569 from OpenStreetMaps.

The result set from this query is multiple ways, which have their role set as `outer`. I am combinining these ways to create a polygon, and storing them in an array.

```
foreach ($geom['members'] as $_poly) {
        if ($_poly['role'] != 'outer' && $_poly['role'] != 'inner') continue;
        if ($_poly['role'] == 'outer') {
            foreach ($_poly['geometry'] as $latlon) $poly['outer'][]=array($latlon['lon'], $latlon['lat']);
        } else {
            $poly['inner'][]=array();
            foreach ($_poly['geometry'] as $latlon) $poly['inner'][count($poly['inner'])-1][]=array($latlon['lon'], $latlon['lat']);
        }
}
if ($poly['outer'][0] != $poly['outer'][count($poly['outer'])-1]) $poly['outer'][]=$poly['outer'][0];
$out['polygons']=$poly;
```

Afterwards, this array is sent to javascript, where I process it, and try to add a Polygon object to an OpenLayers 3 map. This is the javascript code I use. (It is wrapped in a JS prototype made by me)

```
Map.prototype.addPolygon = function(name, data) {

    var _coordinates=[], i;

    for (i=0; i<data.outer.length; i++ ) {
        console.log(data.outer[i]);
        _coordinates.push(ol.proj.transform(data.outer[i], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
    }

    console.log("Creating polygon", _coordinates);
    var Polygon = new ol.geom.Polygon([_coordinates]);
    var feature = new ol.Feature({
        name: name+"-outer",
        geometry: Polygon
    });
    this.polygons[name]=Polygon;

  var polyStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: [121, 115, 251, .2]
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#051165',
      width: 2
    })
  });

  this.vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
  feature.setStyle(polyStyle);

  this.map.getView().fit(Polygon, this.map.getSize()); 

}
```

Below you will find two images, the first is the end result which I get, and the second is the end result which Nominatim gets(my desired result). If you observe, you will see that the borders of my polygon are all messy, and there are additional lines in my polygon.

[My end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEUsn.png)

[Nominatim result - the desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YCmF.png)

What am I doing wrong? If I am doing the same thing with boundaries which are represented by a single `WAY`, everyting works as expected.